# Sluggish input reaction in Chrome on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: google-chrome

I have an issue with the current Google Chrome version 104.0.5112.101 under Ubuntu 22.04: after there is no input (mouse movement, scroll wheel, keyboard etc.) for a few seconds, processing of new input (e.g. trying to scroll using the mouse wheel) is reproducibly delayed, i.e. it takes 1-2 seconds until the page is scrolled. This also happens in other situations:

- when opening the menu and not moving the mouse for a few seconds, when I move the mouse again the "hover highlighting" of the menu items isn't updated for some time.
- sometimes apparently also drawing is affected, e.g. popup menus are shown as empty white rectangles for a few seconds.

As far as I can see this only happens in Chrome. Firefox and other applications are not affected. For some reason, this only happens on some pages (e.g. while entering this question I wasn't able to reproduce it - maybe having an active edit control somewhere on the page prevents the issue from happening?), but it can be reproduced e.g. on Chrome's "About" page (chrome://settings/help).

---

**Update September 23rd:** issue still present in Chrome 105.0.5195.125. It doesn't happen always, sometimes it's present from the beginning of a session, sometimes is starts happening only after a few hours (not sure if there's something specific that triggers it). Restarting Chrome doesn't help, I have to restart the whole system. Apparently an active edit control really stops the issue from happening, pressing Ctrl+F on any page will prevent the issue, but only as long as the search popup is focused.

Comment: This happens to me when the video driver is xorg and chrome's hardware acceleration is turned on. The reason I'm using xorg is that with nvidia, ubuntu freezes when coming back from sleep :(

Answer (score 3):

I was facing some of the issues you were facing and it seems that everything has to do with the video card and the video card driver. If you have an external card drive, I suggest you re/install or install a new driver, such as nvidia driver metapackage. But, if you do not have an external video card, I suggest you turn off hardware accelaration in chrome. In my case, I simply installed a new driver and everything is working fine now.

- You can re/install video card drivers (such as nvidia) under the additional softwares in Softwares & Updates program.
- You can deactivate the hardware accelaration under chrome://settings/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Deactivating hardware acceleration in chrome://settings/ did the trick for me!

Comment: Deactivation of h/w acceleration worked for me too, but mouse response remained sluggish until I rebooted the machine.